# SQL: Inner join with top 2 rows with second table from on condition

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

Hi I am now trying to join 2 table with only 2 rows from second table join to first table.

For example, I have following 2 tables:

```
**Table A**
Column1 |   Column2 |   Column3
A       |   B       |   30
A       |   C       |   50
A       |   D       |   25

**Table B**
Column4 |   Column5
B       |   35  
B       |   90
B       |   65
B       |   80
B       |   85
B       |   40
C       |   100
C       |   60
C       |   70
C       |   65
```

Here is example of my normal query:

```
select *
from 
    (
        select * 
        from A 
        where Column1 = 'A' and (Column2 = 'B' or Column2 = 'C') 
        order by Column2, Column3
    ) A
    inner join
    (
        select * 
        from B 
        where (Column4 = 'B' or Column4 = 'C') 
        order by Column5
    ) B
    on (A.Column2 = B.Column4 and ((B.Column5 - A.Column3) > 30))
```

The Result should look like:

```
**Result:**
Column1   |   Column2 |   Column3 |   Column4 |   Column5 
A         |   B       |   30      |   B       |   65
A         |   B       |   30      |   B       |   80 
A         |   B       |   30      |   B       |   85 
A         |   B       |   30      |   B       |   90
A         |   C       |   50      |   C       |   100
```

However, the result that I want is to join only 2 row from second table result only. The expected result should be:

```
**Expected Result:**
Column1   |   Column2 |   Column3 |   Column4 |   Column5
A         |   B       |   30      |   B       |   65
A         |   B       |   30      |   B       |   80
A         |   C       |   50      |   C       |   100
```

Do anyone have idea of how to create such sql statement? Thank you.

Comment: When you say "2 row from second table result only", what exactly you mean? Do you mean top 2 rows of second inner join query?

Comment: No. Top 2 row that can do inner join from on condition. In this case, it will need to do calculation where Table B Column5 - TableA Column3 is more than 30 also.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? You said No to my question but sound like saying same thing.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new here so when I press enter, it just show my comment. I mean Top 2 row that can do inner join from on condition. In this case, it will need to do calculation where Table B Column5 - TableA Column3 is more than 30 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use row_number() to limit the number of rows.  The example assumes that `(Column1, Column2, Column3)` is unique.  If table `A` has a primary key, use that instead.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  Column1
        ,       Column2
        ,       Column3
        ,       Column4
        ,       Column5
        ,       row_number() over (partition by Column1, Column2, Column3 
                                   order by Column5 - Column3 desc) as rn
        from    A
        join    B
        on      A.Column2 = B.Column4
        where   Column1 = 'A' 
                and Column2 in ('B', 'C')
                and Column5 - Column3 > 30
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn < 2
```

[See example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b865e/14/0)

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to write more simple SQL without the inline views:

```
select *
from   A inner join
       B on (A.Column2 = B.Column4)    
where  A.Column1 = 'A'               and
       A.Column2 in ('B','C')        and
       (B.Column5 - A.Column3) > 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CTE

```
WITH Top2Rows AS (
    SELECT TOP 2 *
    FROM TableB
    WHERE ([ADD CONSTRAINTS])
)

SELECT *
FROM TableA a
JOIN Top2Rows r ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE ([ADD CONSTRAINTS])
```

Comment: `top` is not Oracle.  Even in SQL Server a CTE with `top` wouldn't work.  The condition `Column5 - Column3 > 30` refers to both tables, and has to be run before the `top`.

Comment: In SQL Server `TOP` works in CTE I use it and you can try it. it is a mandatory piece when using `ORDER BY` in CTE as well. For the conditions I set [ADD CONSTRAINTS] which he needs to change depending on his needs. That means he can add any joins he is interested in

Comment: I agree `top` will work in a CTE.  However, `top` cannot pick the top two rows in this scenario because of the `Column5 - Column3 > 30` join condition.  Try it :)